# C/C++ Compound TCP

Tags: c++, c, windows, api, tcp

In the command prompt I could use:

```
netsh int tcp set global congestionprovider=ctcp
```

I'm wondering if there is a way I could accomplish the same thing programically in C/C++ without using system().

I'm assuming i'm probably going to have to use COM?

EDIT: Also information about how I could access other information that I would normally access through netsh in C/C++, would be nice :) (Example: `netsh int tcp show global`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines, this might be achievable using a manual registry modification in the same way described for the [Windows XP/Windows Server 2003 backport of CTCP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949316).  Hypothetically, you would have to set the given value to 1 using [RegSetValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724923%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and inspect it using [RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to see what is the state at this time.

```
When you apply this hotfix, the following registry subkey is created: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
The properties of this subkey are as follows: 
Name: TCPCongestionControl
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1
When the value is set to 1, CTCP support is enabled. When the value is set to 0, CTCP support is disabled.
```

Whether this works for you at all, or without a reboot or not depends on 1) whether the appropriate component auto-detects registry mods and 2) whether that's all there is to it on the newer OSes.  Does not seem like this would be too hard to try out, though.